# Is it possible to incrementally retrieve values from Firestore in a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

"I want to retrieve Firestore documents from a Flutter app, but I don't want to fetch all of them at once. For example, I'd like to fetch five documents in one request, and when a user action occurs, I want to fetch another set of five documents.
I know that I can limit the number of retrieved documents using limit, but with that, I cannot incrementally fetch documents (i.e., I want to fetch another set of five documents from the previously retrieved documents without fetching the same documents again).

How can I incrementally retrieve values from Firestore in a Flutter app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is called pagination, and is described in the Firebase documentation on [paginating data with cursors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors).

I recommend checking that documentation out and trying to make it work based on that. If you get stuck, post a new question with a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Got it! Thank you!